# Set-AzApiManagementPolicy in az cli

Tags: azure-cli, azure-cli2

Is there an `az cli` equivalent command to `azure powershell`'s `Set-AzApiManagementPolicy`? Since `az apim` is still in preview I doubt it, but perhaps there's an `az rest` command I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

As I expected `az rest` [has this functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/apipolicy/createorupdate). I should've spend a few more minutes looking.